# Script to make many markdown files from one json file is adding back in http: and https: prefix to links. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, markdown

I have a large json file that populates a website with questions using gatsby.js (not important for the question) and markdown (important). My data looks something like this.

```
"-JugHeFMJfGN071lmqqo" : {
      "askedHistPercent1" : "58",
      "askedHistPercent2" : "54",
      "askedHistYear1" : "2018",
      "askedHistYear2" : "2015",
      "author" : "Author Name",
      "categories" : [ "Category 1", "Cat 2", "Cat 3" ],
      "date" : "2015-07-20 09:27:29",
      "definition" : "Long Definition here. Includes a now //link to show the content. Was a http://link or https://link before I deleted all the link prefixes with control-f replace",
      "permalink" : "//www.Urlherelong",
      "title" : "Title here"
    },
```

etc for 1600 more items in this .json file. I've built this following script to pull all of the information into markdown files as yaml frontmatter to use with gatsby graphql. It doesn't look pretty, but it works 99.99% of the time

```
const fs = require("fs");
const YAML = require("yamljs");
const bigObject = require("../1111data.json");
var _ = require("lodash");

Object.entries(bigObject).forEach(([name, data]) => {
  fs.writeFile(`${_.kebabCase(data.title)}.md`, "---\r\n", err => {
    fs.appendFile(`${_.kebabCase(data.title)}.md`,YAML.stringify(data),
      err => {
        fs.appendFile(`${_.kebabCase(data.title)}.md`, "\r\n---\r\n", err => {

          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(`${_.kebabCase(data.title)}.md has been saved!`);

        });
      }
    );
  });
});
```

In any case, the script is putting back http and https prefixes onto my url links. The senior devs on my team want me to have // prefixes on all of the urls instead. After removing all the https: and http: from my .json file, poof, they show back up. I'm scratching my head sitting here because I never told them to do so. You'd think the script would be 100% the information it pulls in, right? This is what I get.

```
---
askedHistPercent1: "35"
askedHistYear1: "2008"
assocMediaLink1: ""
author: ""
categories:
  - category1
content: ""
date: "2015-03-05 17:01:55"
definition: "http://link here again. Rest of definition"
excerpt: "yada yada"
id: 14247
permalink: "http://link"
title: "title"
---
```

Is there something I can add to my script to block the re-addition of the http and https link prefixes and keep them //www.etc instead?